# Read a file in dart 2 with dart:io library

Tags: angular, file, io, dart, angular-dart

I'm new in dart language.

I want to read a file (test.txt) using the library dart:io. I based my first tries on this link : 
https://v1-dartlang-org.firebaseapp.com/dart-vm/io-library-tour

but with those try, I still get an error when trying to read the file, I didn't find anything about that so I'm asking here, has anyone any solution or any idea of what might be the problem ?

Here is the code and the file I try to read (encoded in UTF-8).

configReader.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

class ConfigReader{

  ConfigReader(){
    var configFile = new File("test.txt");
    var text;
    configFile.readAsLines(encoding : Encoding.getByName("utf-8"));
  }

}
```

test.txt

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

The error I'm getting :

> EXCEPTION: Unsupported operation: _Namespace STACKTRACE: 
>   dart:sdk_internal
>   readAsLines package:insightos/src/utils/init/configReader.dart 11:15
>   new package:insightos/src/utils/init/utils.dart 35:5
>   getHost package:insightos/src/utils/init/utils.dart 72:13
>   getSandayaNewEndpointService
>   package:insightos/src/utils/linker/query_factory.dart 52:21 
>   loadClientConfiguration dart:sdk_internal
>   async package:insightos/src/utils/linker/query_factory.dart 51:70 
>   loadClientConfiguration
>   package:insightos/src/utils/init/authenticator.dart 85:65    initApp
>   dart:sdk_internal                                            async
>   package:insightos/src/utils/init/authenticator.dart 83:44    initApp
>   package:insightos/src/utils/init/authenticator.dart 66:7
>   initAuthentication package:stack_trace
>   arg package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 190:16            arg
>   dart:sdk_internal                                            runUnary
>   package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 187:18
>   [_runUnary] dart:sdk_internal
>   .scheduleMicrotask.dart.fn
>   package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 163:9
>   safeMicrotask package:stack_trace
>   parent.registerCallback.dart.fn
>   package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 178:16
>   parent.run.dart.fn dart:sdk_internal
>   run package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 175:18
>   [_run]
>
> package:insightos/src/utils/linker/query_factory.dart 51:70 
>   loadClientConfiguration
>   package:insightos/src/utils/init/authenticator.dart 85:65    initApp
>   dart:sdk_internal                                            async
>   package:insightos/src/utils/init/authenticator.dart 83:44    initApp
>   package:insightos/src/utils/init/authenticator.dart 66:7
>   initAuthentication package:stack_trace
>   arg package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 190:16            arg
>   dart:sdk_internal                                            runUnary
>   package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 187:18
>   [_runUnary] dart:sdk_internal
>   .scheduleMicrotask.dart.fn
>   package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 163:9
>   safeMicrotask package:stack_trace
>   parent.registerCallback.dart.fn
>   package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 178:16
>   parent.run.dart.fn dart:sdk_internal
>   run package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 175:18
>   [_run]
>
> dart:sdk_internal
>   async package:insightos/src/utils/init/authenticator.dart 61:40
>   initAuthentication package:insightos/src/utils/init/authenticator.dart
>   58:5               ngOnInit
>   package:insightos/src/components/app_bar/app_bar.template.dart 471:25 
>   detectChangesInternal package:angular/src/core/linker/app_view.dart
>   398:7                    detectChanges
>   package:insightos/src/utils/app/insightOS.template.dart 366:16
>   detectChangesInternal package:angular/src/core/linker/app_view.dart
>   398:7                    detectChanges
>   package:insightos/src/utils/app/insightOS.template.dart 413:16
>   detectChangesInternal package:angular/src/core/linker/app_view.dart
>   398:7                    detectChanges
>   package:angular/src/core/linker/view_ref.dart 106:12
>   detectChanges package:angular/src/core/change_detection/host.dart
>   168:18             [_runTick]
>   package:angular/src/core/change_detection/host.dart 144:15
>   tick package:angular/src/core/application_ref.dart 108:5
>   [_loadedRootComponent] package:angular/src/core/application_ref.dart
>   96:27
>   src__runtime__optimizations.unsafeCast.run.dart.fn
>   package:angular/src/core/change_detection/host.dart 250:18
>   runInZone.dart.fn package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 178:16
>   parent.run.dart.fn dart:sdk_internal
>   run package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 175:18
>   [_run] dart:sdk_internal
>   run package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 327:22
>   run package:angular/src/core/application_ref.dart 140:51
>   runInZone package:angular/src/core/change_detection/host.dart 248:5
>   run package:angular/src/core/application_ref.dart 69:23
>   bootstrap package:angular/src/bootstrap/run.dart 188:16
>   runApp main.dart 8:3
>   main main.dart.bootstrap.js 788:12

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider allows you to get paths to valid directories where applications can read and write. Where did you expect `new File("test.txt")` to come from?

Comment: They are in the same folder so I thought it would grab it as in Python and the example from  https://v1-dartlang-org.firebaseapp.com/dart-vm/io-library-tour
I'm going to try that then, thanks.

Comment: It looks like it requires SDK version <2.0.0 but I'm with dart 2 so I can't use it

Comment: Ok I think I just read something on this  very same link
`Important: Only Flutter mobile apps, command-line scripts, and servers can import and use dart:io, not web apps.`
I need to find another way to read file than using this library I guess

Comment: How is that related to Angular? Are you trying to read files from code shared between Angular and Flutter?

Comment: "They are in the same folder" what is in the same folder with what? "looks like it requires SDK version" what looks like requiring this SDK version?

Comment: configReader.dart is in the same folder as test.txt
I'm just trying to read a .txt file from a Dart 2 code, no Flutter for me.
I tried adding the dependency of the path_provider you gave but it's not supported for Dart 2, only Flutter I think and maybe Dart 1

Comment: Sorry, I thought I saw a Flutter tag. In the browser you can use stuff from `dart:html` to read files. Access to files is quite limited in the browser though. You can use an `<input type="file">` and let the user chose files. You can then read those chosen files in your code. For example like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25568326/dart-upload-file-input-type-file/25568468#25568468

Comment: That's alright, but what I'm trying to do is just to read a .txt file in the dart code. Now I'm reading about the FileReader function from the solution you gave but I don't understand how am I supposed to use it, it requires a Blob and I've never heard of that before.
I tried another method using httpRequest, from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47799327/using-dart-for-html5-app-but-want-to-load-a-file-from-the-server-side
and that worked but only when the file is in a certain folder and I would like to use this method for any .txt file no matter where the .txt file is.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter web does not support `dart:io`. Instead you need `dart:html`

**Solution**

```
readFile(String path) async{
    var request = await HttpRequest.request(path);
    var response = request.response;
    
    return response;
}
```

For context's sake, I used this to read a .svg file as a string. For your use, you will need to modify the method like this:

```
readFile(String path) async{
    var request = await HttpRequest.request(path);
    var response = request.response;
    var lines = LineSplitter.split(response);

    //lines is an SyncIterable<String> but can be converted to a List<String>
    return lines;
}
```